# Editar arquivo txt pelo bat

Tags: windows, script, batch, automatização, txt

Tenho o seguinte problema: Em um diretório do Windows, tenho 3 arquivos `.txt` que todos os dias são criados automaticamente. Dentro deles existem várias linhas com informações. Desejo apagar duas linhas que sempre se repetem em todos os `.txt` e depois salvá-los sem essas duas linhas, continuando no mesmo diretório.

Teria como fazer isso automaticamente com um `.bat`, um script ou algo que possa ser automatizado? Se sim, como posso fazer?

Comment: Essas duas linhas são sempre no começo ou fim do arquivo? ou ela variam?

Comment: Sempre são a segunda e quarta linha, dentro dos .txt

Answer (score 1):

Assim :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%x in (*.txt) do (
        call:skip "%%x"
        )
exit/b

:skip

set/a $c=1

(for /f "delims=" %%a in (%~1) do (
  if not !$c!==2 if not !$c!==4 echo %%a
  set /a $c+=1))>out.txt

move out.txt %1 2>nul
```